# Checking if two n-ary trees are equal in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, equals

I am trying to implement a simple boolean function in Haskell to check if two n-ary trees are equal.

My code is:

```
-- This is the n-ary tree definition.
-- (I know "Leaf a" is not necessary but I prefer to write it for clarity)
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [Tree a]
    deriving (Show)

-- This is a simple tree used for test purposes
t :: Tree Int
t = Node 3 [Node 5 [Leaf 11, Leaf 13, Leaf 15], Leaf 7, Leaf 9]

treeEquals :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
treeEquals (Leaf n1) (Leaf n2) = n1 == n2
treeEquals (Node n1 xs1) (Node n2 xs2) = n1 == n2 && and(zipWith (treeEquals) xs1 xs2)
treeEquals _ _ = False
```

My problem is that if I do tests such as:

```
treeEquals t t
treeEquals t (Leaf 3)
treeEquals t (Node 3 [Leaf 7])
```

it returns correctly false because the trees are not equal, but if I try a test such as:

```
treeEquals t (Node 3 [])
```

It doesn't work because it returns true as the trees were equals.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are there better ways to implement this method without using zipWith avoiding two lists traversals?

Comment: Using `Leaf` in this fashion actually leads to redundant representations: `Node x []` vs `Leaf x`. Redundant representations should normally be used only for a good reason (e.g., if they allow some operations to be much faster). In this case, just dropping the `Leaf` constructor seems likely to be the best course of action. Alternatively, you could change the `Node` constructor to `Node a (Tree a) [Tree a]`, but why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another && before the zipWith and check if the lengths of the lists are the same.

Comment: Doing this means potentially two list traversals - it's better not to use zipWith in the first place.

Comment: @Darwin, thanks for your answer. I had not thought that, it was so simple!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just derive `Eq` and use `==`?

The problem with your current code is the `zipWith`. It stops as soon as it reaches the end of the shorter list, so `zipWith treeEquals foo []` always returns `[]` (regardless of what `foo` is).

Here's an (untested) alternative solution:

```
treeEquals :: Eq a => Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
treeEquals (Leaf n1) (Leaf n2) = n1 == n2
treeEquals (Node n1 xs1) (Node n2 xs2) = n1 == n2 && listTreeEquals xs1 xs2
    where
    listTreeEquals [] [] = True
    listTreeEquals (x1 : xs1) (x2 : xs2) = treeEquals x1 x2 && listTreeEquals xs1 xs2
    listTreeEquals _ _ = False
treeEquals _ _ = False
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have understood what's the problem.
Unfortunately I have to implement my own method because I have to exercise myself for an exam. I am trying to implement all the possible things they could ask me, so I can't just use ==.

Comment: @JohnQ The cool thing about `(==)` here is that even if you don't derive it, but implement it yourself, you can define `(Node n1 xs1) == (Node n2 xs2) = n1 == n2 && xs1 == xs2` [plus the equations for the other cases, `Leaf/Leaf` and `_/_`]. The `xs1 == xs2` then uses the generic `instance Eq a => Eq [a]` to do the right thing. For your `treeEquals`, you could then simply use `treeEquals = (==)` ;)